# How to change style for delete cells button in UITableView for certain rows

Tags: ios, swift

I want for don't editable rows change background color and label for swipe to delete button.
How to do it?

I don't want use `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool`, for disable swipe to delete, because it **less clear** for user in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Write the below tableview method

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        // Detemine if it's in editing mode
        if (self.tableView.editing) {
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
        }
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
```

Comment: It is disable EditingStyle, I need change UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete (color foe delete button)